# ReferenceError: toRefs is not defined

Tags: nuxt.js, vitest

I am trying to use vitest with nuxt 3. Since,nuxt has auto-import feature I am not importing it but when I am writing unit test in vitest its giving me error `ReferenceError: toRefs is not defined` how to solve this. I am new to vitest.

I tried to render the component and it should be render but getting error.
[image]

Comment: can you please share the nuxt version?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.